# Why do some liquids rise up exposed rotating shafts?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Practical experiment observations. Some liquids appear to be drawn up the rotating shaft  and some seem to be drawn down. Vortex and non vortex effects do not immediately seem to have any effect

Comment: google on non-newtonian fluids, also shear-thickening and shear-thinning.

Comment: Does this possibly have to do with the ratio of cohesion to adhesion for the liquid?

Comment: Google "rod climbing effect for viscoelastic fluids."

Answer (score 0):

Look up the Weissenberger effect. Physics and maths not explained, but phenomena is clearly demonstrated in Lab trials.